# Redis doesn't start when run as service - can't chdir: permission denied

Tags: redis

I have been running redis which I built from source for several months, but I switched to using a package manger for it today (running on Debian). It ran fine until I changed the working directory to `/home/redis/server`. Now when starting it as a service using `sudo service redis-server start`, I get an error, and the following is added to the redis log:

```
Can't chdir to '/home/redis/server': Permission denied
```

Running `getfacl` recursively on the redis directory returns

```
# file: .
# owner: redis
# group: redis
user::rwx
group::rwx
other::rwx

# file: server
# owner: redis
# group: redis
user::rwx
group::rwx
other::rwx

# file: server/dump.rdb
# owner: redis
# group: redis
user::rwx
group::rwx
other::rwx
```

If I `su` to redis and run it manually, using `/usr/bin/redis-server /etc/redis/redis.conf`, it works correctly, so it only happens when trying to use the included init.d script.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It turns out that the init script included with Redis isn't actually used, and instead it uses `/etc/systemd/system/redis.service`. There are a number of security restrictions in this file, including `ProtectHome=yes` and limiting the directories that can be written to. I have modified this file to comment out `ProtectHome=yes` and to add a line `ReadWriteDirectories=-/home/redis/server`, and it now works correctly.

After this, run `systemctl daemon-reload` to reload changes before running `service start redis-server`.

Answer (score 0):

You should make sure, that the redis service is started by init.d with the redis user context.

Edit `/etc/init.d/redis-server` and add

```
--chuid redis:redis
```

where `start-stop-daemon` is called. Since `su` to redis is working, this should fix the error.

Comment: `--chuid` is already in there, by default, though I did try `chmod`ing the directory to 777 and that still didn't resolve it.

Comment: Since you don't get the error if you start `redis-server` as `redis (user)`, I would try to start the server with: `su redis -c 'redis-start-command'` in the `init.d` file. This is not the best solution, but might work.

Comment: Also check if `redis-server` ist really running as `redis (user)` `ps u pid-of-redis-server` or `ps aux | grep redis-server`

Comment: For some reason, running `sudo su redis -c "/usr/bin/redis-server /etc/redis/redis.conf"` in the terminal fails silently (nothing logged), and only seems to work if I actually su to redis, then run it manually. Redis is definitely running as user redis.

Comment: Actually, adding `-s /bin/bash` to the end of the command works, but I'd still like to be able to stop redis if possible, which manually running it wouldn't allow I think.